# How to use directives when you have inline template in Angular 6 component?

Tags: angular

I have a simple angular component (web component) that, instead of having a separate `.html` file with the template, it has the `html` markup written inline, like this:

```
import {
  Input,
  Component,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  EventEmitter,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';

const heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-button',
  template: `
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        {{ hero }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    button {
      border: solid 3px;
      padding: 8px 10px;
      background: #bada55;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  `
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() label = ' label';
  @Output() action = new EventEmitter<number>();
  private clicksCt = 0;

  handleClick() {
    this.clicksCt++;
    this.action.emit(this.clicksCt);
  }
}
```

I then use this component as a custom element to display it in `index.html` file. The problem is, when I open the application, none of my content is being rendered. Instead, I get this in inspect mode:

[image]

If I remove the `ngFor` directive, the static content renders fine. The problem is when I use directives to list through arrays only.

What could be the issue?

Comment: The heros array is expected to be a property on the component, not a global const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];`

needs to be added to the properties of the ButtonComponent class:

```
export class ButtonComponent {
  ...

  heroes: string[] = heroes;
}
```

Globals and imports aren't made available to the binding context of the component unless they're made a property.

Comment: Solved, accepting this as the answer in a few minutes (answer was too quick)! :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @BlueBird03, even though this solution works **you should really avoid defining Global variables in the first place.** Instead in your component you should consider updating the code to be `public heroes: string[] = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];`

Comment: @Narm I agree. It should be exported from a shared place, or just made part of the component itself.